# csv file: error in uploading

Tags: csv

I'm uploading Accounts in my org but the system doesn't let me do it. The values are separated by commas and at every end line there is '/r'.

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to substitute

```
 "/r" with "/r "/n"
```

It's the command for

```
 "end line"
```

May this will help you !!